# CS1002 ; Expected. I've got a semicolon and don't see anything wrong

Tags: c#

So I'm using the following code: `float double x;` and I keep getting the CS1002 error. I'm not sure what's wrong. I've tried retyping the code and looking back at older projects that have worked. It's still giving me the console error.

Answer (score 2):

Both `float` and `double` are data types.  You need to pick one or the other.  A single variable cannot have two different data types.

```
float x;  // declares a single-precision floating point variable
double x; // declares a double-precision floating point variable
```